# there was an error in parsing the query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

error:

```
[token line number = 1,token line offset = 15,token in error = %]
```

my code:

```
 SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
 cmd.Connection = con;
 cmd.CommandText = "select emails from contacts where name like %@name";
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
 SqlCeDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 //..
```

I believe it is because the @name in query.
I tried too: `select emails from contacts where name like '%@name'`

how I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide `%` from SQL parser, because it is part of the string literal:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "select emails from contacts where name like @name";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "%"+name);
SqlCeDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
select emails from contacts where name like '%'+@name
```